# display other button when asynchronous task completed in place of previous button Android

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons images names are: "download","send".first when I click on download button asynchronous process will started and when download completed then progress bar disappearing and another button image name  "send" will show in place of "download" button and send button disappearing when I click on send image button then I will go next activity through intent.

my code for async task is..and here I only use only one button...please do modify in my code...

```
private class createCSV extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private Context context;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         dialog = new ProgressDialog(CsvSender.this);
         dialog.setMessage("Processing...");
         dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
         dialog.setCancelable(false);
         dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing())
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        //some stuff here for back ground operation

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

            if (dialog.isShowing())
            {
            dialog.dismiss();
         //change the visibility of byttons
          download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          send.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

This idea may solve your problem.